# Прокрутка страницы ниже, чем окончание кода?

Tags: phpstorm

При написание кода в PhpStorm у меня остается маленький кусок страницы снизу, после которого прокрутка страницы ниже прекращается:
[image: Снимок IDE 1]

Можно конечно через Enter создать еще пачку пустых строк, но не думаю, что это хороший вариант:
[image: Снимок IDE 2]

Вопрос: где в настройках PHPStorm (если такого в настройках нет, то какой плагин посоветуете), чтобы сделать область после кода больше, а лучше вообще ее отключить, чтобы можно было крутить страницу в низ неограниченно?

Comment: А зачем это вам?

Comment: Монитор бывает разный, а нижнюю строку кода высматривать где то там в низу достаточно не удобно. Гораздо удобнее прокрутить ее к центру монитора...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `General` : `Show virtual space at file bottom` = `yes`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]